# outerHTML behavior in a <template>

Tags: html, dom, web-component, html5-template

Given this `<template>`:

```
<template id="my-template">
    <h1 id="h">Hello!</h1>
</template>
```

And JS:

```
var t = document.querySelector("#my-template");
var h = t.content.querySelector("h1");
h.outerHTML = "<h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>";
```

It's interesting that it works in FireFox and Edge but in Chrome `outerHTML` requires a parent element, otherwise it throws error in console (https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/dom/Element.cpp#2528):

```
<template id="my-template">
    <div>
        <h1 id="h">Hello!</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/q5fmn186/11/

My question is, is Chrome behavior the correct one? Should setting `outerHTML` not work in `<template>` on direct children? Why aren't the other web-browser treat it like an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other web browsers won't treat it like an error because they are following the [DOM Parsing and Serialization W3C Candidate Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#widl-Element-outerHTML) (which is not a standard yet):

> On setting **[outerHTML]**, the following steps must be run:
>
> 1. Let parent be the context object's parent.
> 2. If parent is *null*, terminate these steps. There would be no way to obtain a reference to the nodes created even if the remaining steps were run.
> 3. If parent is a *Document*, throw a *DOMException* with name *"NoModificationAllowedError"* exception.
> 4. If parent is a *DocumentFragment*, let parent be a new *Element* with body as its local name, the HTML namespace as its namespace, and the context object's node document as its node document.
> 5. Let fragment be the result of invoking the fragment parsing algorithm with the new value as markup, and parent as the context element.
> 6. Replace the context object with fragment within the context object's parent.

The `<template>`'s `content` is of type *[DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)* (step 4) but it is treated (in this situation) as a *Document* (step 3) by Chrome and Safari.

Comment: thank you very much. So on longer term, we should expect to see Chrome and Safari follow the recommendation (which eventually hopefully will become a standard)?